# Detect collision from different objects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I couldn't come up with a suitable title for this question but I'll explain.

I have a collision box, which holds a script. This script has an if statement that detects collision from object "Cube001" and sends a Debug.Log to console.

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;

 public class cubeDetect : MonoBehaviour {

     void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {

         if (collision.gameObject.name == "Cube001")
         {
             Debug.Log("Cube001 hit!");
         }
     }

 }
```

With this method, the box collider knows what cube has touched it, as I have instructed so with

```
collision.gameObject.name == "Cube001"
```

But say if I have 10 cubes colliding with the collision box, how can I change the if statement so instead of writing another 9 if statements that check if it touches the collision box, I can just have 1 if statement that just first **detects a collision from another cube**, knows **what cube hit the box**, and with this knowledge, is able to **do a Debug.Log to display the name of the cube** that hit the box.

I've tried going through the documentation for `OnCollisionEnter` but couldn't find anything to help with this.

Comment: use tags instead of the object name for checking (and only put the `name` in the `Debug.Log`)

Comment: @UnholySheep Tag still requires many `if` statements. I think that OP want's to remove the many `if` statements required to do this

Comment: Hi @UnholySheep, if I use tags then each cube will be essentially the same object, which just spreads my issue to multiple objects

Comment: @toadflax Does each object have unique name?

Comment: If all cubes use the same tag then there is only a single `if` required. And I don't know what you mean by *"will be essentially the same object"*, they are still separate objects

Comment: @Programmer Each cube is labelled "Cube001, Cube002, Cube003, ..." by default, which can be changed if need be. I'm just struggling to find a way for the collision box to know which box has hit it.

Comment: @UnholySheep They're same objects but the if statement will be sending Debug.Log messages each time any cube hits it. It wouldn't actually know which cube is hitting it as long as it has the same tag.

Comment: @toadflax of course you know which one hit, it is a unique gameobject in your scene. And if you gave them all unique names then you can just access its `name` property and use that (like you are doing for your check right now)

Comment: @toadflax if you give them the same tag, you can still print the unique name of the object, as my solution below states... and therefore determine the unique object that has collided. all of the gameobject's information is stored in the collision object that is passed to the OnCollisionEnter function

Comment: @toadflax You can do this with a tag or the name with mutlple `if` statements but why did you ask this question? To do this without multiple `if` statements or you don't care?

Comment: @Programmer I wanted to do this with preferably 1 if statement, so the collision box knows what cube has touched it, then I want to somehow store that "last" cube's information in a variable each time, which would allow me to use that variable and perform different outcomes to different cubes.

Comment: @toadflax That's what I though this question is about but wanted to verify. I can put an answer with if one statement if you are still interested. If you have already found your answer then that's fine and you should accept it.

Comment: @Programmer oh definitely still interested! I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to tag all of your similar objects you want to collide with, with the same name. Say we give them the tag "Cubicle". Then we can do the following:

```
Gameobject myCube;
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {

     if (collision.collider.tag == "Cubicle")
     {
         Debug.Log(collision.gameObject.name + " hit!");
         myCube = collision.gameObject; // store colliding gameobject info for use elsewhere
     }
 }
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this answer, I've voted this up. This method seems to work! But is there a way I can store the information of the last cube that hit the box in a variable that is usable outside of this if statement?

Comment: absolutely, just declare a variable outside the function and store the collider info in it. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `Dictionary`. This eliminates the need for all the `if` statements.

This is what the `Dictionary` should look like:

```
public static Dictionary<GameObject, System.Action> objToAction = new Dictionary<GameObject, Action>();
```

Then a function to add objects to the dictionary when they are instantiated or in the `Start` function if they already exist

```
public void registerObject(GameObject obj, System.Action action)
{
    objToAction.Add(obj, action);
}
```

The key in the `Dictionary` is the GameObject(Cube), you can also use string(name of the GameObject) but using the GameObject is better. The value in the `Dictionary` stores what you want to to do when `OnCollisionEnter` is called. *So the code that should've been inside that `if` statement should be placed here.* This is done with `Action` and `delegate`. You can add as many GameObjects (Cubes) as you wish.

You must add those Cube Objects to the Dictionary with the function above:

```
public GameObject prefab;

void Start()
{
    //Create new Cube
    GameObject obj = Instantiate(prefab);
    obj.name = "Cube001";

    //Add it to the Dictionary
    registerObject(obj, delegate { Debug.Log("Hit: " + obj.name); });
}
```

Your new `OnCollisionEnter` code is as below. No `if` statement required. If the Object exist in the `Dictionary`, execute that code we stored in the value of that `Dictionary` for each key GameObject.

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    Action action;

    if (objToAction.TryGetValue(collision.gameObject, out action))
    {
        //Execute the approprite code
        action();
    }
}
```

Note that the `objToAction` variabel should either be made `static` or placed in another script attached to an empty GameObject so that you can access it. There should only be one instance of it.

Answer (score 1):

What was working best for me was to use interfaces and components and check for that. This is working great if you have certain logic on collision but when you don't you can just use `tag` and set it to something like `"collidable"`.

*interfaces solution:*

```
public interface ICollidableObject
{
    void CollidedWith(ICollidableObject other);
}

public class CollidableBlock : MonoBehaviour, ICollidableObject
{
    public void CollidedWith(ICollidableObject other)
    {
        Debug.Log((other as MonoBehaviour).gameObject.name);
    }
}

public class CollidableSphere : MonoBehaviour, ICollidableObject
{
    public void CollidedWith(ICollidableObject other)
    {
        Debug.Log("sphere001");
    }
}
```

And just use it like such :

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) 
{
    ICollidableObject collidedWith = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<ICollidableObject>();
    if ( collidedWith != null )
        collidedWith.CollidedWith(this);
}
```